# text_format field value not appearing in full_html mode

Tags: forms, 8, plugins

I'm using a block plugin to display content based on what the user inputs into a form. Select boxes, and radio buttons are saved and displayed in the form just fine but the text_format field isn't working the same way.

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

    $form['bodytext'] = array(
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#title' => $this->t('Block contents'),
      '#format' => 'full_html',
      '#description' => $this->t('This text will appear in the block.'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['bodytext-submit'],
    );
}

public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $this->configuration['bodytext-submit']  = $form_state->getValue('bodytext');
}
public function build(){

    return array(
        '#title' => '',
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => '<div>' . $this->configuration['bodytext-submit']['value'] . '</div>',
    );
}
```

Anything input into the text_format element in the form is saved properly but when returning to the form, the field is empty unless the format is set to 'basic_html'.
So I know the values are being saved, and are even presently available in the configuration form of the block. It simply isn't displayed in 'Full_html' mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by eliminating the '#format' specification in the blockForm function
and specifying the value of bodytext-submit rather than just bodytext-submit. Like so

```
    $form['bodytext'] = array(
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#title' => $this->t('Block contents'),
      '#description' => $this->t('This text will appear in the block.'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['bodytext-submit']['value'],
    );
```

Comment: Adding the ['value'] without removing the '#format' worked for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to eliminate the #format.

The format and value of the text_format are stored as an array. So in the same way as you retrieve the value you can retrieve the format.

See this example:

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $body = !empty($this->configuration['body']) ? $this->configuration['body'] : '';
  $form['body'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#title' => 'Body',
    '#format' => isset($body['format']) ? $body['format'] : 'full_html',
    '#default_value' => isset($body['value']) ? $body['value'] : '',
  );
  return $form;
}

public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->configuration['body'] = $form_state->getValue('body');
}
```