# Custom block build function to display wysiwyg body text

Tags: 8, blocks

I am learning to build custom blocks through a module. I am trying to get the build() function to work. I have the code and it works. However, if I edit the configuration of the block as a user it does not print the text in the text formatter.

```
'#markup' =>
    '<div>' . $this->t('Body: @body', ['@body' => $this->configuration['body']]) . '</div>',
```

In the rendered block on the page it prints... Body:
But not the text in the wysiwyg.

Any ideas how to get that to work. The tutorials and links I am finding are not relavant.

Comment: So I figure out that - $this->configuration['body']['value'] -- prints the text from the wysiwyg in the configuration but it prints the html. Now I need to figure out how not to ... Anyone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to safely render node body on a custom variable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable)

Comment: ☝️ replace node with block, same procedure. I suggest you go with the 2nd approach of **Render element in php** solution

Comment: Thank you for you response. However, 4k4's answer more fits what I am looking for. I was not trying to integrate twig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you store the block configuration via a `text_format` form element as in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/278811/47547

*src/Plugin/Block/ExampleBlock.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides an example block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "mymodule_example",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Example"),
 *   category = @Translation("mymodule")
 * )
 */
class ExampleBlock extends BlockBase {

  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $body = !empty($this->configuration['body']) ? $this->configuration['body'] : [];
    $form['body'] = [
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#title' => 'Body',
      '#format' => isset($body['format']) ? $body['format'] : 'full_html',
      '#default_value' => isset($body['value']) ? $body['value'] : '',
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->configuration['body'] = $form_state->getValue('body');
  }
```

You would output the wysiwyg content via `processed_text`:

```
  public function build() {
    $build = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      'label' => ['#markup' => 'Body: '],
    ];
    if (!empty($this->configuration['body'])) {
      $build['body'] = [
        '#type' => 'processed_text',
        '#text' => $this->configuration['body']['value'],
        '#format' => $this->configuration['body']['format'],
      ];
    }
    return $build;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Honestly, this is so much more than I was expecting. I did not see anything like this while I was looking. I would love a link to a Drupal API or something page as well if you can. Trying hard to learn but it is taking longer then I thought. I appreciate the complete code share. I tried it and it worked perfectly. Now I need to learn this and keep going. Thank you!!!